# SQL: Getting items which have a max value in another tables column, but also match some cross table clauses

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

This is probably a really basic question but I have spend a lot of time on this.

I have 2 Tables:

**Files**

```
| FileId | Type | FolderId |
----------------------------
|   1    | txt  |    11    |
|   2    | xml  |    15    |
|   3    | xml  |    17    |
|   4    | txt  |    19    |
```

**Folders**

```
| FolderId |   path    | version | typeId |        
-------------------------------------------     
| 11       | //c:/here | 1       |    1   | 
| 19       | //c:/here | 3       |    1   | 
| 15       | //c:/dummy| 6       |    1   | 
| 17       | //c:/dummy| 4       |    1   |
```

I want it to return: All info from `Files`, with the highest `Folder.Version` number, where the `Files.type`, `Folders.path` and `Folders.typeID` all match.

Essentially I need to group by `Files.type`, where `Folders.path` & `Folders.typeID` are the same. Then return the item with the max version field for each group.

So in the example above I would want the output:

```
| FileId | Type | FolderId |
----------------------------
|   2    | xml  |    15    |
|   4    | txt  |    19    |
```

So far I have the query below, which I think is ok for getting the items with the highest version number when TypeId and path match (I think????). But I cannot figure out how to group by Files.Type.

```
SELECT * FROM Files
WHERE FileId IN (
  SELECT FileId   FROM Files
  WHERE FolderId IN (  
    SELECT fo.FolderId                   
    FROM Folders fo                
    LEFT JOIN Folders fo2      
        ON fo.Path = fo2.Path AND fo.TypeId = fo2.TypeId    
        AND fo.Version < fo2.Version            
    WHERE fo2.Version IS NULL
  )
)
```

Can anyone explain how I can get this query done? I have a feeling I need some group by statements but I can't figure it out!

This is SQL server 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify a verson of SQL Server.

```
select Files.*
from
    Files inner join
    (
        select f1.FolderId
        from Folders f1 inner join
            (
                select TypeId, Path, max(Version) as MaxVersion
                from Folders
                group TypeId, Path
            ) as f2
            on f2.TypeId = f1.TypeId and f2.Path = f1.Path f2.MaxVersion = f1.Version
    ) Folders
        on Folders.FolderId = Files.FolderId
```

If you have a later edition of SQL Server then this should work too:

```
select Files.*
from
    Files inner join
    (
        select first_value(FolderId)
            over (partition by TypeId, Path order by Version desc) as FolderId
        from Folders
    ) Folders
        on Folders.FolderId = Files.FolderId
```

EDIT: Maybe this is the fix per your comment:

```
select Files.*
from
    Files fi inner join Folders fo on fo.FolderId = fi.FolderId
    inner join
    (
        select "Type", TypeId, Path, max(Version) as MaxVersion
        from Files fi2 inner join Folders fo2 on fo2.FolderId = fi2.FolderId
        group "Type", TypeId, Path
    ) as mv
        on      mv."Type" = fi."Type"
            and mv.TypeId = fo.TypeId and mv.Path = fo.Path
            and mv.MaxVersion = fo.Version
```

I'm in a rush but I think this might work on SQL Server 2012:

```
select distinct
    first_value(FileId)
        over (partition by "Type", TypeId, Path order by Version desc) as FileId,
    "Type",
    first_value(fo.FolderId)
        over (partition by "Type", TypeId, Path order by Version desc) as FolderId
from
    Files fi inner join Folders fo on fo.FolderId = fi.FolderId
```

Comment: Thanks for such a fast response. I have edited my post to show I am using SQL server 2012.

For your first solution, it does not group by the Files.Type field. Do you know where that should be included?
The scheme is a little confusing having a TypeId and a seperate Type column.

Comment: I initially caught that you had three columns in the grouping but I did overlook that when writing those queries. It does definitely change things.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. It is easy to understand also. I did not think I could use select statements inside an inner join statement, which is going to be useful for me in future.

Thanks a lot. I have marked your reply as answered. Unfortunately I don't have enough rep to upvote you yet, but once I do, I will come back :)

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
select f.*
from files f
inner join folders dir on f.folderid = dir.folderid
inner join (
  select type, max(version) maxver
  from files fi
  inner join folders fo on fi.folderid = fo.folderid
  group by type
) t on f.type = t.type and dir.version = t.maxver
```

Result:

```
| fileid | type | folderid |
|--------|------|----------|
|      4 |  txt |       19 |
|      2 |  xml |       15 |
```

Since SQLFiddle SQL Server 2008 and 2014 were not responding well, I created an example with MySQL here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7abd4/13. I expect the query results to be identical for SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Simple top-1-per-group, isn't it?

One possible variant using `ROW_NUMBER`.

`PARTITION BY Files.Type, Folders.path, Folders.typeId` define the groups, 
`ORDER BY Folders.version DESC` define which row to pick for each group.

More efficient than self-join.

```
WITH
CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        Files.FileId
        ,Files.Type
        ,Files.FolderId
        ,Folders.path
        ,Folders.typeId
        ,Folders.version
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY Files.Type, Folders.path, Folders.typeId 
            ORDER BY Folders.version DESC) AS rn
    FROM
        Files
        INNER JOIN Folders ON Folders.FolderId = Files.FolderId
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
;
```